# Select rows that are full in SQL

Tags: sql, database

How can I select the rows in a table that are full without adding " WHERE a_column > '0' " for each column in the table?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking but you could define a computed column that evalutes each required column value, you then only need to check the computed column.

Comment: Do you mean rows without any NULL values?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify each column, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE NOT (col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL ...)
```